# Power management dies after suspend in Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, suspend, kde, power-management

Ever since I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10 from 14.10 power management dies after waking up from suspend (to disk or ram). The only thing that still works is dim display but it won't even un-dim. Screen does not turn off, system doesn't go to sleep on timer or anything. I can get it back by logging out and in again but that makes suspend rather pointless. Unfortunately just restarting upowerd isn't the solution. But what is?

This all used to work just fine in Kubuntu 14.10. System is Lenovo Thinkpad X201.

Answer (score 0):

As it sometimes happens, taking the time to formulate a question in writing can give one ideas. It came to me I might take a look at what powertop says when power management doesn't work and it does show (after sleep) that power saving is off for wifi (probably not significant) and also that USB auto-suspend is off for the 3G modem so it's active 100% of the time. So just doing what powertop proposes after sleep is one part of it. Although I have never done this for systemd before (i.e. run my own script after suspend), I just have a script for it so far.

The other part of this issue seems to have do with the way KDE power management works these days: it basically disables power management when it thinks some app is busy. At least that's shown in the battery applet but usually that means it thinks Chromium is busy. So sometimes killing Chromium is needed as well.